# What's the most convenient way to run queue:work on production?

Tags: laravel, queue, production-environment

I'm working on a digital product based on laravel. In which i use laravel queued
jobs.

While creating the documentation I've figured out that it's not that familiar to run the queue listener/worker on production for non-tech clients.

Is there any kind of easy way to achieve that without setting up a process monitor or a job sheduler?

I've tried to create a route where clients can run `Artisan::call('queue:work --once')` whenever they have dispatched jobs, but it seems not a good idea.

Any help?

Comment: check laravel [vapor](https://vapor.laravel.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact reason why you need a Daemon, so for example **Supervisor** as a tool is great fit. Read this section out of Laravel Docs (copied below)
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

And if you are using Laravel Forge, or Vapor, then it's a breeze!

```sh
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

Supervisor configuration files are typically stored in the `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` directory. Within this directory, you may create any number of configuration files that instruct supervisor how your processes should be monitored. For example, let's create a `laravel-worker.conf` file that starts and monitors **queue:work** processes:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

Comment: Not everyone has a root access, can setting up supervisor be a problem?

Comment: No, not at all, however, it will take up some of your RAM and CPU resources so make sure not to place too many process, stick with low number like 3 of your server's sepcs are not that high

Comment: In Shopware 6 (a Symphony App) the Queue processing is handled via Kernel command and time limit of 60s `--max-time=60`, initiated by cron jobs. I think in a pinch this might be also an option